# Problemas con URL al importar un video en React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hola tengo el problema al importar una url local de un video.
La ruta esta bien ya que es similar a la de imagenes que importo y tienen la misma jerarquia en ubicación.

```
import Banner from '../../../../../assets/video/banner.mp4' //no funciona
import Logofrom '../../../../../assets/image/logo.png' //funciona
```

Y no importa de la forma que lo intente usar, ya me marca error en la Url, si en el src del video coloco el '../../.. ...banner.mp4' me marca error el `not find module ...`

Comment: ¿Tienes un fichero .d.ts donde has declarado el módulo con las imágenes?

Comment: es de una pagina que ya existia por lo que no se muy bien el tema de configuraciones que tenga pero el .d.ts que tengo unicamente sale esto (se llama react-app-env.d.ts) : 

/// <reference types="react-scripts" />